# Class Name not being added to Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a pop up modal and when I click a button I add a class changes the display property from 'none' to 'block'. It worked fine at first then I appended some HTML to the body via JS and since then it hasn't worked.

```
// Open modal
function openModal(clicked_id) {
  var button = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
  var modal = button.getAttribute("data-modal");
  var modalElement = document.getElementById(modal);
  document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='modal-backdrop' class='modal-backdrop'></div>";
  var backdrop = document.getElementById("modal-backdrop");
  backdrop.className += " modal-open";
  modalElement.className += " modal-open";
  // Close Same Modal Event Handlers
  (function() {
    document.getElementById("modal-close").onclick = function(e) {
      closeModal(modalElement, backdrop);
    }
    document.getElementById("close").onclick = function(e) {
      closeModal(modalElement, backdrop);
    }
    document.getElementById("modal-backdrop").onclick = function(e) {
      closeModal(modalElement, backdrop);
    }
  })();
}
```

From debuggin I can see that element is being selected and the class name is added to the class list, but this isn't reflected on the computed HTML. I tried moving the line:

```
 modalElement.className += " modal-open";
```

above the line:

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='modal-backdrop' class='modal-backdrop'></div>";
```

But then the close functions stopped working. There's no errors in the console and the debugger runs the code as if it worked so I'm stumped. I have a code pen that shows everything bought together: http://codepen.io/WebDevelopWolf/pen/XMZdBg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `+=` (or string concatenation) for appending to the `body`, use `document.createElement()` and `body.appendChild(element)` to append the new element to the `body`. This small change will get your modal working again.

```js
// Open modal
function openModal(clicked_id) {
  var button = document.getElementById(clicked_id);
  var modal = button.getAttribute("data-modal");
  var modalElement = document.getElementById(modal);
  var backdrop = document.createElement('div');
  backdrop.id="modal-backdrop";
  backdrop.classList.add("modal-backdrop");
  document.body.appendChild(backdrop);
  backdrop.classList.add("modal-open");
  modalElement.classList.add("modal-open");
  // Close Same Modal Event Handlers
  (function() {
    document.getElementById("modal-close").onclick = function(e) {
      closeModal(modalElement, backdrop);
    }
    document.getElementById("close").onclick = function(e) {
      closeModal(modalElement, backdrop);
    }
    backdrop.onclick = function(e) {
      closeModal(modalElement, backdrop);
    }
  })();
}

// Close Modal
function closeModal(modalElement, backdrop) {
  modalElement.className = modalElement.className.replace(/\bmodal-open\b/, '');
  backdrop.className = backdrop.className.replace(/\bmodal-open\b/, '');
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
body {
  background: #0881a3;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#heading {
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: #e1e1e1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 {
  text-transform: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-size: 13px;
}

#trigger {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal {
  color: #1f4e5f;
  background: #a4e5d9;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  z-index: 1050;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity .15s linear;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
  -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
  opacity: 1;
  display: none;
}

small {
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}

.modal-body,
.modal-footer,
.modal-heading {
  padding: 25px 20px;
}

.modal-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c8f4de;
}

.modal-heading h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-heading h2 i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.modal-heading .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 17px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.modal-heading .close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #c8f4de;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal-footer button,
#trigger button {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #649dad;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#trigger button {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.modal-footer button:hover,
#trigger button:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #009ac9;
  border-color: #009ac9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 0;
  display: none;
}

.modal-open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f79e01ac29.js"></script>
<div id="heading">
  <h1><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> Akela - The Pure JS Pop-up</h1>
  <h3>A lightweight modal pop-up with no framework dependancy that's mobile friendly.</h3>
</div>

<!--Modal Trigger-->
<div id="trigger">
  <button id="staticbtn" data-modal="static" onClick="openModal(this.id)" class="btn btn-info">Show Static Modal</button><br />
  <small><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Made with the help of Font Awesome <i class="fa fa-star"></i></small>
</div>

<!--Static Modal-->
<div id="static" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-heading">
      <h2><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> Hello World</h2>
      <div class="close"><i id="close" class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      I'm a pop up!
    </div>
    <div id="modalFooter" class="modal-footer">
      <button id="modal-close" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great thanks - just so I can understand though - how come that fixes it? Is it something to do with how the DOM updates?

Comment: despite what it may look like, `element.className` / `element.innerHTML` (and all other properties accessed this way) are not simple strings, and therefore the += operator doesn't work. You can, however, achieve the intended effect through `element.className = element.className + " modal-open";`.

Comment: To expand on @GameGibu, I believe what was happening was due to how `innerHTML` works. When using `innerHTML += `, it will destroy and rebuild all descendant elements of the container, which removes any existing event listeners bound to any child elements. In your case, this means the event listener on the Close button was removed.